# What is an efficient way to calculate rankings based on specific votes from a large database?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, performance, bigdata, database-performance

Here's how my site works now, which for simplicity's sake, let's say is a movie rating site:

Users can cast either an upvote or downvote on movies. Movies have an **approval rating**, which is the ratio of upvotes to downvotes:

```
@m.approval = @m.upvote_count / (@m.upvote_count + @m.downvote_count)
```

and a **relevance rating**, which is the movie's percentile rank on a list of *all* movies, ordered by total votes:

```
@m.relevance = Movie.where("votes_total < ?", @m.votes_total).count / Movie.count
```

So my model `Movie` has five attributes: `:upvote_count`, `downvote_count`, `:votes_total` (upvotes + downvotes), `:approval`, and `:relevance`.

When a vote is cast, either `:upvote_count` or `:downvote_count` are increased by one, and then `:votes_total`, `:approval`, and `:relevance` are recalculated based on the new vote counts. Simple enough.

---

But now I want to be able to capture data about the people casting the votes, and calculate ratings based on that data. For example, on my home page there is a list of the 10 highest-approved movies, and another of the 10 most relevant. I want to be able to change the setting so that I see these top 10 lists based on votes cast only by certain people, say 18-20 year old males in the USA. In other words, I want to be able to see the top-10 movies for various demographics.

The method that immediately comes to mind is to create a `Vote` model with `:up_or_down`, `:age`, `:nationality`, and `:gender` attributes, and then calculate the ratings based on these, on page load. But I'm pretty sure this would be impossible for any mortal server, given the large number of movies and votes, and the complexity of the ratings calculations. As you can see, to calculate the `:relevance` for each and every movie, every single vote in the database would have to be retrieved. Currently that's about 500,000 records being retrieved about 3,000 times, for a total of 1,500,000,000 retrievals on every page load.

I also considered just adding more attributes to `Movie`, so the ratings would be stored, for example `:18_to_20_approval`, `:male_relevance`, etc. But I would have to add so many for all the different age groups and nationalities and other criteria, that I think this is also unfeasible. Plus, I would no longer be able to mix different criteria, like 18-20 males. I could only view 18-20, and then separately also view males.

Does anyone have any ideas for how I could accomplish this and still complete the calculations in a reasonable amount of time? Also let me know if any additional clarification is needed.

Comment: Sounds like a problem ElasticSearch could solve (or Solr/Lucene).

Comment: about ranking u also may be intereseted in reading this http://www.evanmiller.org/how-not-to-sort-by-average-rating.html

Comment: @jlhonora Do you really think those programs could allow for the retrieval of over a billion records in a reasonable amount of time?

Comment: I don't think this is something you will be able to calculate dynamically and there is probably no reason to. I would recommend calculating periodically (and storing/caching) a top-10 list for each category you would like to display. You will really only have to consider movies/votes that that were cast since the last re-calculation so it should be fast.